# I have made 2 android app. with Timepickers, I have written same code but one is working, the other is not

Tags: java, android

I have tried to figure out what the problem is , but seems like I am just getting more n more hopeless by time. The class "Promillekalkulator" is working fine, but the other class "Beregning" is not even opening. The error says I have to fix setCurrentTimeOnView method, but I have exactly the same method on the class "Promillekalkulator". Any help would be really appreciated :////

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class Beregning extends Activity{
TextView pil, klokkeslett;
    Button btnFerdig;
TimePicker timePicker1;
private int hour1;
private int minute1;
private int hour2;
private int minute2;
Calendar c;

static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beregn);
    initCommonGui();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    initListeners();

}


public void initCommonGui(){
    pil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pil);
    klokkeslett = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.klokkeslett);
    btnFerdig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFerdig);
}

private void setCurrentTimeOnView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute1 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
     klokkeslett.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour1)).append(":")
                .append(pad(minute1)));
        timePicker1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

}

private void initListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    pil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });

    btnFerdig.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            otherActivity("resultat_promille");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour1,     minute1,
                false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour2 = selectedHour;
        minute2 = selectedMinute;

         klokkeslett.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour2)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(minute2)));
        // set current time into timepicker
        timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour2);
        timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute2);

    }
};



private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}

public void otherActivity(String a){
    Intent i=new Intent();
    if(a.equals("resultat_promille")){
        i.setClass(getApplicationContext(),Resultat_Promille.class);
    }
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}

}
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
    android:text="cl"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="%"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:text="40" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:text="50" />

 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:text="60" />

 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:text="3,5" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:text="4" />

 <RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="190dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="167dp"
    android:text="4,5" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
     android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton4"
     android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
     android:text="Klokke" 
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/pil"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton5"
     android:text="->"
     android:textColor="@color/darkgreen" 
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

 <TimePicker
     android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="450dp"
   />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/btnFerdig"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginLeft="140dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="310dp"
     android:text="Ferdig!" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/klokkeslett"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/pil"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/pil"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/radioButton6"
     android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the other program "Promillekalkulator" which is working perfectly fine

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Promillekalkulator extends Activity {

/**
 * @param args
 */
TextView textView5;

TimePicker timePicker1;
Button button1;


private int hour1;
private int minute1;
private int hour2;
private int minute2;
Calendar c;



static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 999;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_promillekalkulator);


    initCommonGui();
    setCurrentTimeOnView();
    initListeners();

}

private void setCurrentTimeOnView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 c = Calendar.getInstance();
    hour1 = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute1 = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    // set current time into textview
    textView5.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour1)).append(":")
            .append(pad(minute1)));

    timePicker1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

private void initListeners() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }

    });
}
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        // set time picker as current time
        return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour1, minute1,
                false);

    }
    return null;
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new     TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute) {
        hour2 = selectedHour;
        minute2 = selectedMinute;

        // set current time into textview
        textView5.setText(new StringBuilder().append(pad(hour2))
                .append(":").append(pad(minute2)));

        // set current time into timepicker
        timePicker1.setCurrentHour(hour2);
        timePicker1.setCurrentMinute(minute2);

    }
};



private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}


public void initCommonGui() {

    textView5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



}

}
```

XML Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:text="@string/klokkeslett"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="22sp" />

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
    android:text="@string/velg" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the error:
01-25 17:37:04.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.example.rustelefon.Beregning.setCurrentTimeOnView(Beregning.java:50)
01-25 17:37:04.255: E/AndroidRuntime(1542):     at com.example.rustelefon.Beregning.onCreate(Beregning.java:32)

Comment: noOne there to help ://///

Comment: Can you exactly mention the error you are getting?

Comment: they are telling that I have to fix setCurrentTimeOnView method and specially underlining this line in the method "timePicker1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);"... but if u see my class Promillekalkulator, it has exactly the same methods .. n its working

Comment: You haven't shown us the actual error. You've posted two lines of the stack trace, but you haven't even shown us what type of exception is being thrown. If you want more help, put more effort into writing a good question - ideally with *much* less code. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not initialised timePicker1 in your Beregning activity. Add the initCommonGui() method in your Beregning class and call it from the onCreate method before calling setCurrentTimeOnView().

Comment: I acually have written the lines in the onCreate method, but didnt make the method "initCommonGui", but I am making now.... hope it will workk ://///

Comment: its still not working :// It says to fix setCurrentTimeOnView

Comment: you can find the error log at the end of my Long question :(((

Comment: @user2855719: No, we can find a *tiny bit* of the error log, which fails to include the important information.

Comment: You are still not initialising timepicker1 in your initCommonGui method. Add this line

timePicker1 = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);

and also make sure that the layout activity_beregn contains timePicker1